# Google Drive UI Integration not working for all in domain

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a running web application complete with OAuth2 set up in Google Cloud Console under the company organization. It has Drive API enabled. It is accessible to all users in my company's domain.

I want to do Drive UI integration for the web app so that it is available for use with "New" and "open with " options in Google Drive. I followed the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/enable-sdk) and was able to submit the form for Drive UI integration. The app shows up for me in my Google Drive. It doesn't show up for other users in my domain. The admin has third party apps enabled for all in the organization.

In the Google cloud console, I have set the webapp as User type:- Internal in the OAuth consent screen. I am not sure what settings are to be changed to make the integration available for all in the domain.
Kindly help. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue. This was happening because the domain user in question [ who did not get the webapp drive UI integrations ] was a test user who has not authorized the web app. Once the URL of the web app was used to authorize it, the 'New' and "open with" integrations showed up for them as well.